# Truncations of a series for the inverse tangent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a rapidly convergent series of the inverse tangent function. It is an interesting paper by Sofo and Villacorta (see the article here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273126245_NEW_IDENTITIES_FOR_THE_ARCTAN_FUNCTION) where the inverse tangent is given by this series
$$\small\tan^{-1} z=z\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}{2{{\left( -1 \right)}^{i}}{{z}^{2i}}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{nm}}{{z}^{2n\left( m+1 \right)}}{{4}^{n}}\left( \begin{aligned} & 2nm+2i \\ 
& nm+i \\ 
\end{aligned} \right)}{\left( n+1 \right){{\left( 1+{{z}^{2}} \right)}^{n}}\left( \begin{aligned}
& 2\left( nm+i+n+1 \right) \\ 
& nm+i+n+1 \\ 
\end{aligned} \right)\left( \begin{aligned}
& nm+i+n+1 \\ 
& nm+1 \\ 
\end{aligned} \right)}}$$
When I truncated this equation (with respect to index $n$) I observed that accuracy is dependant on $m$. Suppose I take $N$ terms in truncation. How to choose the integer $m$ to get the most accurate approximation in truncation at given $N$?